# WQL Clause "WITHIN" doesn't working in Powershell v5

Tags: powershell

I am trying to execute a process memory usage watcher.

Here is the code:

```
 $Poll = 120
$query = "Select * from CIM_InstanceModification within $Poll where TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process' AND TargetInstance.WorkingSetSize>=$(500MB)"

$action={
#create a log file
$logPath= "C:\Users\phant\Documents\Powershell\LOGS\MEM.txt"
"[$(Get-Date)] Computername = $($_.SourceEventArgs.NewEvent.SourceInstance.CSName)" | Out-File -FilePath $logPath -Append -Encoding ascii
"[$(Get-Date)] Process = $($_.SourceEventArgs.NewEvent.SourceInstance.Name)" | Out-File -FilePath $logPath -Append -Encoding ascii
"[$(Get-Date)] Command = $($_.SourceEventArgs.NewEvent.SourceInstance.Commandline)" | Out-File -FilePath $logPath -Append -Encoding ascii
"[$(Get-Date)] PID = $($_.SourceEventArgs.NewEvent.SourceInstance.ProcessID)" | Out-File -FilePath $logPath -Append -Encoding ascii
"[$(Get-Date)] WS(MB) = $([math]::Round($_.SourceEventArgs.NewEvent.SourceInstance.WorkingSetSize/1MB,2))" | Out-File -FilePath $logPath -Append -Encoding ascii
"[$(Get-Date)] $('*' * 60)" | Out-File -FilePath $logPath -Append -Encoding ascii

#create a popup
$wsh = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.shell
$Title = "$(Get-Date) High Memory Alert"
$msg = @"
Process = $($Event.SourceEventArgs.NewEvent.SourceInstance.Name)
PID = $($Event.SourceEventArgs.NewEvent.SourceInstance.ProcessID)
WS(MB) = $([math]::Round($Event.SourceEventArgs.NewEvent.SourceInstance.WorkingSetSize/1MB,2))
"@

#timeout in seconds. Use -1 to require a user to click OK.
$Timeout = 10
$wsh.Popup($msg,$TimeOut,$Title,16+32)

}

Register-CimIndicationEvent -Query $query -SourceIdentifier "HighProcessMemory" -Action $action
```

I tried using __InstanceModificationEvent instead CIM_InstanceModification. I got the same value, NULL.

When I try in a powershell console I get this error:

```
   $Poll = 120
    $query = "Select * from CIM_InstModification within $Poll where TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process' AND TargetInstance.WorkingSetSize>=$(500MB)"
    Get-WmiObject -Query $query

Get-WmiObject : Consulta invalid "Select * from CIM_InstModification within 120 where TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process' AND TargetInstance.WorkingSetSize>=524288000"
line:1 character:1
+ Get-WmiObject -Query $query
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ManagementException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
```

Always when I use the clause "WITHIN" the query doesn't work. Both CIM_InstModification and __InstanceModifcationEvent are compatible with it. So what is wrong? Someone have a idea?

Thanks!

Comment: `$_` -> `$Event`, `SourceInstance` -> `PreviousInstance`.

Comment: I did as you mentioned above. However I get the same error "0x80041017" Invalid Class. In powershell and wbemtest, same error. When I execute the whole script I don't get error, instead I receive blank values in the popup and log File as shown in that picture: http://i.imgur.com/7UcfZgV.png

Comment: I am invoking this command: `Register-CimIndicationEvent -Query "Select * from __InstanceModificationEvent within 10 where TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process' AND TargetInstance.WorkingSetSize>=$(500MB)" -Action { $Event.SourceEventArgs.NewEvent.PreviousInstance | Out-Host }` — and it work just fine.

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm.